# How can I send the parent object for a property selected in the Angular Material Autocomplete?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm working with Angular 4 Material, and specifically the Autocomplete component.

My list of options **filteredHomeTeams** is of type **Observable< Team[ ] >** and I'm building the dropdown and the selection using a property of such object called **teamName**

Here is the HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Local" [formControl]="HomeTeamCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="homeAuto">
            <mat-autocomplete #homeAuto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="setHomeTeam()">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let team of filteredHomeTeams | async" [value]="team.teamName" >
                        {{ team.teamName }}
                    </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

As you can see I have an event called **optionSelected** that calls a method setHomeTeam()

My Team class is:

```
export class Team {
    teamName: string;
    teamSelfRef: string;
}
```

What I need to do, and this is probably very basic for experienced angular programers is:

I selected **team.teamName** in the dropdown, and I have **team.teamName** in the input field. 
How can I pass the **team.teamSelfRef** from the same object as a parameter to "setHomeTeam()"?

I need to build and select the object based on the name, but I need to trigger logic with a different property.

It would also work if I can pass the entire object as parameter to the method "setHomeTeam()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you set each option value as a team instead:

```
[value]="team"
```

And then you can pass that entire team object. You would have to define a display function for your autocomplete, to display the team name instead of team object:

```
<mat-autocomplete [displayWith]="displayFn" ...
```

And in your class:

```
displayFn(team: Team): string {
    return team? team.teamName: team;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Alic W is correct, which is btw explained in the docs: **[Setting separate control and display values](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#setting-separate-control-and-display-values)** The addition to Alic W's code is how to get the value you desire.

So as Alic W said, you bind the object with `value`:

```
[value]="team"
```

and add the `displayWith`:

```
<mat-autocomplete #homeAuto="matAutocomplete" 
                  [displayWith]="displayFn"  
                  (optionSelected)="setHomeTeam()">
```

The `displayFn`:

```
displayFn(team: Team): string {
    return team? team.teamName: team;
}
```

and then you can access the complete object (including the `teamSelfRef`) property from your form control `HomeTeamCtrl`:

```
setHomeTeam() {
  console.log(this.myControl.value.teamSelfRef)
}
```

Here's a demo from the docs and their variables: https://plnkr.co/edit/zlKFIytpI6pokfZi3ofm?p=preview